# How to change relay nickname of an existing tor relay?

Tags: configuration, relays, consensus

my tor relay has been active for 30 days and was down for 2 to 3 days. when it was down, i changed the relay nickname field in the torrc . its been 24 hours but the relay nickname is not being reflected in the consensus.

What should i do ?

Comment: Is it changed now? Should be.